# How to display specific data of current user from firebase to new activity?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a problem with my codes whereby I cannot display data (input from the previous activity) to a new activity.

[this is my data in the firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Mv4.png)

[this is my current output, the BMI is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrbll.png)

[what I want is this, the BMI value is not null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yD0mt.jpg)

Here is my current code of HomepageActivity:

```
private void viewBMI() {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Users").child("bmi").child(uid);

    // Read from the database
    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String finalBmi = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            showBMI.setText("BMI:  " + String.valueOf(finalBmi));

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            //Log.w(BMI, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
```

This is the code from previous activity:

```
private void updateBMI(double bmi, final FirebaseUser currentUser) {

    kg = Double.parseDouble(inputKg.getText().toString());
    m = Double.parseDouble(inputM.getText().toString());


    metricFormula = new MetricFormula(kg, m);
    imperialFormula = new ImperialFormula(kg, m);

    //bmi = String.valueOf(TWO_DECIMAL_PLACES.format(metricFormula.computeBMI(metricFormula.getInputKg(),metricFormula.getInputM())));
    bmi = Double.parseDouble(TWO_DECIMAL_PLACES.format(metricFormula.computeBMI(metricFormula.getInputKg(),metricFormula.getInputM())));

    final double finalBmi = bmi;

    mAuth.updateCurrentUser(currentUser).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

            UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdate = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                    .build();

            currentUser.updateProfile(profileUpdate)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){

                                Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
                                values.put("bmi", finalBmi);

                                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                        .updateChildren(values).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            //acc successfully registered
                                            showMessage("Account Updated");

                                            updateUI();
                                        }
                                        else{
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });

}

//next page
private void updateUI() {

    Intent homepageActivity = new Intent(EditProfileActivity.this,HomepageUser.class);
    //homepageActivity.putExtra("bmi",bmi); //new
    startActivity(homepageActivity);
    finish();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think,
Your reference is not reaching correctly

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Users").child("bmi").child(uid);
```

there is no child "bmi" under "Users"

In your image, you have 
Users -> JKkaSDGLdkM7HxzBKf1ivJ4G6A03 -> bmi...etc

there is another layer you need to account for reaching the information.

Answer (score 0):

Your order of child access is incorrect. As i can see in the image of Firebase Child Hierarchy you have 'bmi' under 'userID'. So replace

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Users").child("bmi").child(uid);
```

with

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Users").child(uid).child("bmi");
```

Since hierarchy structure is Users->id->bmi(a component of jason object)

Comment: it didnt work, after I changed it, the app totally stop